# Is it correct to say "He walked towards the direction of xx"?

Tags: grammar

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/direction?s=t), "direction" means:

> the point or region itself

Thus, the sentence can be something like: *He walked towards the northern region.*

But also according to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/towards?s=t), "towards" means:

> in the direction of

So in other words, the sentence would be: *He walked in the direction of the direction of xx* or *He walked in the direction of the northern region.*

However, even so, would that make sense? Or is having both "direction" and "towards" reductant?

Comment: Are we just allowed one word and can it have only one meaning?  "Direction" also means north, south, east and west where "towards" does not.  You can walk "towards" your car or away from your car.  Your company can move in the "direction" of the future or "towards" a more simple time.  Sorry, but I'm not really sure what you're asking.  (FWIW, I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: It ***can be*** redundant: *"he walked towards the direction of north"* could be replaced by *"he walked north,"* and *"he walked towards the direction of the store"* by *"he walked towards the store."* But is it always? Is redundancy bad? Sometimes it can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direction is an orientation, like north or left. You can not walk towards a direction, as it is an infinite line, not a place. You can only walk *in* a direction. However, you can walk towards *the* North, as the North is a place.

- She walked north.
- She walked towards the North.

Answer (score 2):

To make the sentence into a better one, we can say: "He walked towards XX." or "He walked in the direction of XX."  But not "He walked towards the direction of XX." Because the word *towards* itself carries the meaning of *direction*.